# Security warning when running JavaFX project in IntelliJ on MacBook

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, javafx

I've recently migrated from Windows to Mac, and getting set up with IntelliJ and JavaFX. I've
(1) downloaded the JavaFX libraries (to my /Users/xxxxx/downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib directory),
(2) created a 'hello world' project and got it to build
(3) set the VM configuration to "--module-path /Users/xxxxx/downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

(following instructions in https://openjfx.io)

... when I run it, I get a pop-up saying that "libprism_es2.dylib" (in the 'lib' directory) cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. There's a second one saying the same about "libglass.dylib".

How do I persuade the Mac that these files may safely be opened? They were downloaded from gluonhq.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your mac does not trust the file, and there is no way to establish trust because of the method of execution. I ran into the same issue, the solution is to navigate to the lib folder that contains all of the dylib files. Right click on each of the dylib files and click open. It will give you a popup questioning you on whether or not you want to trust this file, click open. Once you go through and trust each dylib file, you should be good to execute your javafx application.

Run that process on all of these files:

```
libdecora_sse.dylib 
libjavafx_font.dylib    
libprism_common.dylib
libfxplugins.dylib  
libjavafx_iio.dylib 
libprism_es2.dylib
libglass.dylib      
libjfxmedia.dylib   
libprism_sw.dylib
libglib-lite.dylib  
libjfxmedia_avf.dylib
libgstreamer-lite.dylib 
libjfxwebkit.dylib
```

Pass it forward ;).